# R Raster Package: Function to determine upper limit for maxmemory

Tags: r, memory, r-raster

Is there a function that lets me determine the maximum value that I can set for `maxmemory` in the `rasterOptions()` command?
I know that this setting is limited by the machine's RAM and each raster cell's size in terms of byte - which is why the upper limit of includable cells (`maxmemory`) depends the respective dataset.

The function I am searching for should therefore be able to produce the hypothetically feasible upper `maxmemory` bound given a certain raster file.

Thank you for your advice.